# Does System.Threading.Thread means same in .NET Core as in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, cross-platform, .net-standard

In `.Net Framework` creation, *call `Start()` actually*, of a `System.Threading.Thread` leads to call to OS, *Windows based systems*, kernel to provide brand new thread for the caller process.

Does things changes in `.Net Core`? Does is it do the same thing on Linux or Mac OS - calls a OS kernel to create a brand new Thread and instance of `System.Threading.Thread` class wrap actual OS thread?

If it's not then how can i describe what is `System.Threading.Thread` are in `.NET Core` cross-platform world?

Comment: Yup, same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the CLR is using OS threads.

To start a new thread, the CLR calls `CreateThread`. On Windows, this is directly mapped to the Win32 API. On Unix, it goes through [an indirection](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/b2031a14a3b110f8e712abdb0cd392c54cd2e839/src/pal/src/thread/thread.cpp#L489) which ends up calling [`pthread_create`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/b2031a14a3b110f8e712abdb0cd392c54cd2e839/src/pal/src/thread/thread.cpp#L758)

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide some documentation references?

Comment: Sources are great, but I guess there is some conceptual description for that solution, like in .net standart mb...

Comment: @no.Oby https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/threading.md  `Just as the JIT compiler maps "virtual" IL instructions into native instructions that execute on the physical machine, the CLR's threading infrastructure maps "virtual" managed threads onto the native threads provided by the operating system.`

Comment: God bless you, Kevin!)